# How to change the color of one of my 5 tabs in react-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, react-bootstrap

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey="recent" >
  <Tab eventKey="recent" title="Recent">
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="popular" title="Popular">
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="all" title="All">
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="category" title="Category">
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="myconversation" title="My Conversation" >
  </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

I have five tabs in one of the component, I want to change the font color of only one tab 'My Conversation'. I tried adding a class both to the parent as well as child but it is not changing the color. Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `tabClassname` to `<Tab />` component, like this:

```
<Tab tabClassName="color-red" eventKey="profile" title="Profile">
  Tab Profile content
</Tab>
```

and a bit of CSS Styling:

```
.color-red {
  color: red;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-item.show .nav-link, 
.nav-tabs .nav-link.active.color-red {
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in `<Tab tabClassName='text-light'/>`  Here are some Bootstrap Colors:

text-secondary

text-success

text-danger

text-warning

text-info

text-light

text-dark

text-muted

text-white`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try this code

```
<Tab eventKey="myconversation" title="My Conversation" style={{ color: "red" }} >
  </Tab>
```